# ocaml top level and native library

Tags: c, interface, ocaml, command-line-arguments

I have a library that calls C code. It's compile with the -custom, -cclib, -l flags, which is working ok when I compile my code against the library with ocamlc,

but when I use the "ocaml" top level to run a script like:

```
ocaml -I /opt/godi/lib/ocaml/pkg-lib/xxxx xxx.cma myprog.ml
```

it says:

```
Error: The external function `caml_yyyy' is not available
```

Do I need additional parameters to tell the top level ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should build your own toplevel using "ocamlmktop":

> $ ocamlmktop -custom -I /opt/godi/lib/ocaml/pkg-lib/xxxx xxx.cma -o ocaml_with_xxx

Then, you can use it :

> $ ./ocaml_with_xxx  -I /opt/godi/lib/ocaml/pkg-lib/xxxx

Note that you still need the -I so that the toplevel can find the interface files of the library that it contains.

Answer (score 2):

IIRC you cannot use libraries compiled with `-custom` in toplevel. You should compile dynamically-loadable stubs so that toplevel could pick up them. This is very easy to do with e.g. [oasis](http://oasis.forge.ocamlcore.org/) and somewhat more involved if invoking ocaml tools manually.